# no suitable conversion from std::string to int

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to use some of the function of standard C library but I got this error: no suitable conversion from std::string to int. I have just stepped into learning C++ from C. Please don't over explain this thing with difficult terms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <cctype>

using namespace std; 

int main(void)
{
  string s1{ "Hello" }; 
  bool what{ isalnum(s1) }; 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried consulting a [reference documentation for `isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum)? What has it told you?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: because there is no function overload of isalnum that takes a parameter of a string.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec sorry i forgot that ctype function takes a single character at time. I should have used `for( auto c: s1) if(isalnum(c)) cout << c; `

Comment: @Angew or even the c++ documentation for [`std::isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalnum)

Comment: @Mgetz Sure, but that's not what the OP is trying to use.

Comment: @Angew I try to encourage the use of the C++ way of doing things on C++ questions. Particularly since the C functions use global state and may lock (given the multithreaded memory model in C++ 11).

Comment: @Mgetz Fair enough, good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isalnum` tells you whether a single character, not a whole string, is an alphanumeric.

If you want to check whether the string is alphanumeric, you'll need to look at each character, either with a loop:

```
bool what = true;
for (unsigned char ch : s1) {
    if (!std::isalnum(ch)) {
        what = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

or an algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool what = std::all_of(s1.begin(), s1.end(), 
    [](unsigned char ch){return std::isalnum(ch);});
```

As mentioned in the comments, there are many complications and deathtraps when using character classification functions, even though they appear to do something simple. I think my examples avoid most of them, but tread carefully.

Comment: @Mike Seymour sorry i forgot that ctype function takes a single character at time. I should have used `for( auto c: s1) if(isalnum(c)) cout << c; `...Thanks for such a nice answer

Comment: Sadly `std::isalnum`is overloaded so this will not work if `<locale>` has been included as well. One solution is  `std::all_of(s1.begin(), s1.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::isalnum(c); })`

Comment: Sadly this also relies on the C global locale, a better alternative would be to use the c++ [`std::isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalnum) which takes a locale as a parameter and thus doesn't rely on global state.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: That's nasty. Once again, I'm glad I never need to use `<locale>`.

Comment: @Mgetz and make the loop var `unsigned char`, so we don't get sign extension artefacts on passing as `int` into `isalnum`

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this so that the C++ way of doing this is also here. I prefer this way as it has less dependency on global state

```
std::locale locale; // grab the current global locale locally, may lock
bool what = true;
for (auto ch : s1) {
    if (!std::isalnum(ch, locale)) {
        what = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

and the algorithm way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>
#include <functional>

std::locale locale; // grab the current global locale locally, may lock
auto isalnum = std::bind(std::isalnum<char>, std::placeholders::_1, locale);
bool what = std::all_of(s1.begin(), s1.end(), isalnum);
```

Note: you have to specialize the `std::isalnum` template to `char` because otherwise `std::bind` has no idea what it's binding too.